# Need help understanding 2D arrays

Tags: vb.net

I have some code written but have a difficult time understanding what parameter is what.

```vb
For row = 0 To 2
            For col = 0 To 2
                rowTotal += magicSquare(col, row) 'I want to know if the parameter called col is actually the column going down the way or if it is the row.

            Next
```

Comment: It doesn't matter.  The *usual* interpretation is that the row is the highest dimension, so appears first in the index expression.  It does make an enormous difference to efficiency, you always want to increment the lowest dimension the quickest.  That indexes the array in storage order, most friendly to the processor caches.  So opposite of what you are doing here.  Swap it to (row, col) and it will make sense to everybody.

Answer (score 1):

While visualizing arrays with a specific orientation of rows and columns is helpful, it's worth noting that it only really "matters" that you stay consistent. For a 2D array, the first parameter is a the length of an array containing arrays of length equal to the second parameter. You can think of this as as the number of rows, but it's all in how you traverse the array.

Thinking in terms of (row,column) is often used because traversing things from left->right and top->down is conventional to reading/writing in a variety of languages. You can think of it as (column,row) as long as you make sure that you're treating those parameters to refer to that throughout your code.

Basically, imagine a spreadsheet with sequences of numbers assigned to categories. You can put the categories so that they're broken up per row, or per column. It doesn't really matter, so long as you make sure you keep following your own convention.

Comment: "For a 2D array, the first parameter is a the length of an array containing arrays of length equal to the second parameter." Yes, in C# [FirstDimensionLength, SecondDimensionLenght] but in vb.net it is (ubound, ubound) An array in C# declared with [7,3] would be (6,2) in vb.net.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the layout of whatever board you're using as well as the `magicSquare` method.

In general you can picture the layout of a 2D array visually by how you would assign it:

```
int[][] arr = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
]
```

`arr[0]` would now return the array `[1,2,3]` and `arr[0][1]` would return the second item in that array - i.e. 2. There's no inherent way to lay this out in columns or rows, you could do it either way. But usually it's easier to treat it as you do visually to keep things orderly.
If the code you were provided names the first parameter "column", you should feel free to believe it's actually the column though. If you're still uncertain or the code is untrustworthy, you can check it out by taking a look at how the arrays are accessed.

Comment: Except the question is asking about vb.net

Comment: I was just providing some pseudocode to explain the lack of connection between the concept of columns/rows and 2D arrays. However you'd be right in that the indexing is off.